# Why isn't my Ruby frequency hash adding values?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash, frequency

I'm trying to find the frequency of values in an array using a frequency hash.  However, my frequency hash isn't grouping the array items properly - they're all being counted just once.  Here's my code:

```
require 'time'
require 'date'   

def peak_hours(reg_date)
    arr = []
    freq = Hash.new(0)
    format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"
    arr << DateTime.strptime(reg_date, format).hour
    arr.each { |v| freq[v] += 1 }
    puts freq
end

contents.each do |row|
    reg_date = peak_hours(row[:regdate])
end
```

Here's the output:

```
{10=>1}
{13=>1}
{13=>1}
{19=>1}
{11=>1}
{15=>1}
{16=>1}
{17=>1}
{1=>1}
{16=>1}
{18=>1}
{21=>1}
{11=>1}
{13=>1}
{20=>1}
{19=>1}
{21=>1}
{16=>1}
{20=>1}
```

Can anyone tell me why the keys are each being counted once, rather than returning a frequency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `arr` and `freq` objects are local to the `peak_hours` method, so they are destroyed whenever the method ends. It looks like you are calling the `peak_hours` method for every reg_date, and each time you call it it's making a new array and a new frequency hash, putting just the one value in each of them.

I think what you want to do is make your frequency hash right before wherever you are looping through your reg_dates, then update the frequency hash for each reg_date right inside the loop.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the code to show where I loop through a csv file ('contents') to get reg_date.  Can you tell me how I would "update the frequency hash for each reg_date right inside the loop"?  It seems that no matter where I put it, it's either inaccessible because it's a local variable, or it gets recreated and wipes out the value.

Comment: This helped.  I'll post my solution below.  It's not very elegant so if you have suggestions they would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I found, with the help of Jeremy Ruten's comment.

```
def peak_hours(reg_date)
    arr = []
    format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"
    arr << DateTime.strptime(reg_date, format).hour
end

freq = Hash.new(0)
contents.each do |row|
    arr = []
    reg_date = peak_hours(row[:regdate])
    reg_date.each do |i|
        arr << i
        arr.each { |v| freq[v] += 1 }
    end
end
puts freq
```

It seems kind of clunky so any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Glad you got it working. The reason it seems clunky is because there's an unnecessary part: the `arr` arrays. You're only ever putting one thing into the array before the array gets reset. I think your `peak_hours` method (which should really have a different name at this point) should take a reg_date and just return its hour. And then your `contents.each` loop should just have two lines of code in it: one to convert the current row's regdate into an hour, and the other to update the frequency hash for that hour.

Answer (score 0):

Remember to indent properly. Try this out for readability:

```
def parse_date(date)
  format = "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"
  DateTime.strptime(date, format).hour
end

hours = contents.map { |row| parse_date(row[:regdate]) }

peak_hours = Hash.new(0)
hours.each { |hour| peak_hours[hour] += 1 }
p peak_hours
```